# Using Indy units to do File encryption?

Tags: delphi, encryption, indy10

I am in the process of converting a database server from Windows to Linux using Delphi 10.4.
The Server uses the Indy units for the TCP encryption to the Clients.
But all data saved on disk is using the LockBox3 kit... And this is NOT compatible with Linux.
So I am trying to find a way to encrypt Streams for saving on disk.

Would there be a way to use the Indy components to achieve this, so I do not have to find yet another 3th party component for disk encryption?

Comment: Encryption is unbound to the media (disk or memory or network traffic). Unless "TCP encryption" is TLS/SSL then just do what is done there, but this time for files. Also for executing Windows executables on Linux consider [WineHQ](https://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: Indy is a communications library, not a file management library. It doesn't implement any encryption outside of SSL/TLS for TCP connections.

Comment: Okay, I was kind of hoping that there would be a way to use the already used SSL system to store data also on disk. In this case I have to find another way. Thanks Remy.